# SSRS returns #Error instead of a message

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am new to SSRS and I have created a simple SSRS report which inserts data in an SQL table and then selects data from the table to display. I am displaying some messages based on the data.

For ex, if the user tries to insert duplicate records into database, the stored procedure returns a message saying "Registration number already exists."

Here is the textbox which is used to display the message,

```
<Textbox Name="invoice_number">
   <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
         <Paragraphs>
            <Paragraph>
              <TextRuns>
                 <TextRun>
                     <Value>=Format(Fields!invoice_number.Value)</Value>
                        <Style>
                           <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                        </Style>
                 </TextRun>
               </TextRuns>
             <Style />
          </Paragraph>
        </Paragraphs>
        <rd:DefaultName>invoice_number</rd:DefaultName>
           <Style>
             <Border>
               <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                  <Style>Solid</Style>
             </Border>
             <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
             <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
             <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
             <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
          </Style>
</Textbox>
```

My report does not return this message but instead it returns #Error. Is it a formatting issue?

Comment: "I have created a simple SSRS report which inserts data in an SQL table" => this sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Could be anything.  When you run the report in preview mode in BIDS/VS, does anything show in the Error List tab?

Comment: where that #Error is returned? in a specific field? please post some sql code and/or an image with the actual error.

Comment: @TabAlleman There is nothing in the error list tab.

Comment: To be clear, when you preview the report, you DO see "#Error" in the textbox in the report, but you don't see any error messages in the error list?   If that is the case, then the next step is to check the SSRS error logs.   If you are not sure where to find them, you can google for your version/edition of SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

How are you handling your datasets?

If you are trying to display the message parallel to the insert operation then you might have to configure the data source accordingly.

[SSRS: Dataset2 not showing data inserted in Dataset1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547967/ssrs-dataset2-not-showing-data-inserted-in-dataset1)

Comment: No. It is If Else in sql. If the condition meets, then insert else select from the table. So it is single transaction.